# Add PIM role assignment with PowerShell - Access issue

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-entra-id

I want to create an Azure DevOps pipeline that creates role assignments to Groups, Resources and AD.

In the script that is executed by the pipeline I try to run the following command:

```
Open-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest -ProviderId 'AzureResources' -ResourceId "$resourceID" -RoleDefinitionId "$roleId" -SubjectId "$userId" -AssignmentState "$AssignmentType" -Schedule $schedule -Reason "Test PIM Automation"
```

All the properties are correct but I still get the following error.

```
##[error]Error occurred while executing OpenAzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest 
Code: UnauthorizedAccessException
Message: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
InnerError:
  RequestId: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXX
  DateTimeStamp: Tue, 12 Mar 2024 07:42:00 GMT
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
HttpResponseStatus: Completed
```

**The service connection that the pipeline uses has Owner role in the Subscription that the resource exists**

*I want to execute this also for ProviderId = 'aadGroups'. Please tell me what kind of access should I have.*

**Update (4/4/2024):**

The AzureADPreview module does not support execution in Azure DevOps pipelines. If I have any update in this, I will also update it here.

Comment: Could you include what Azure AD roles the service principal has under tenant?

Comment: It actually has Owner in the Management Group that includes the Subscription that the resource exists. I cannot understand why it is forbidden to add RBAC role assignment to resource with this access. I would appreciate also if you tell me what role does the service principal need for all the cases because I cannot find it.

Comment: Ok I will check it out but are you sure that the cmdlet Open-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest does not work? Because the scenarios I want to run can be implemented with this, as the documentation says. If I give to the service principal the Privileged Role Administrator will this cmdlet work?

Comment: AAD(or named Microsoft Entra ID) role assigment and Azure Subscription RBAC role assignment are two different things, Open-AzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest seems to be an AAD related command, so your service principal need the AAD related roles not the subscription related.

Comment: Try granting **Privileged Role Administrator or Global Administrator role** to the service principal under the tenant to resolve the error

Comment: I added the **Privileged Role Administrator** to the service principal under the tenant and I had another error after that. `Message: {"errorCode":"PermissionScopeNotGranted","message":"Authorization failed due to missing permission scope PrivilegedAccess.ReadWrite.AzureADGroup,PrivilegedAccess.Read.AzureADGroup.","instanceAnnotations":[]}`

Comment: I resolved this error by giving these permissions to the service principal and I have another error know. `##[error]Error occurred while executing OpenAzureADMSPrivilegedRoleAssignmentRequest 
Code: UnauthorizedAccessException
Message: Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.
InnerError:
  RequestId: XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX
  DateTimeStamp: Fri, 15 Mar 2024 08:26:33 GMT
HttpStatusCode: Forbidden
HttpStatusDescription: Forbidden
HttpResponseStatus: Completed`

Answer (score 0):

If your user account has the **Owner** role in an Azure subscription:

- When you manually create a service principal in an AAD (Microsoft Entra ID), the service principal would not inherit the full permissions form your account. On same resources within the subscription, it might just have the **Contributor** role.
- When you create an ARM service connection ([Azure Resource Manager service connection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/service-endpoints?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#azure-resource-manager-service-connection)) with the '**`automatic`**' option, it will automatically create a service principal for your user account. This service principal would just have the **Contributor** role on most resources by default, and also might not have access on some resources (such as Azure Key Vault) by default.

  [image]

Only the **Owner** role has the permissions to do role assignment. So, you need to check and ensure the service principal has the **Owner** role within the subscription.

Similarly, if you want to use the service principal to do role assignment on AAD (Microsoft Entra ID) level, it needs the **Privileged Role Administrator** or **Global Administrator** role in the AAD.

---

**EDIT:**

Assigning AAD level roles is not available when using the ARM service connection, since its scope is only on **Subscription** or **Management Group** rather than AAD.

In pipeline, you need to use the '[**`az login`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az-login-examples)' command to log in the AAD with the service principal.

```bash
az login --service-principal -t {tenant} -u {username} -p {password}
```

---

**EDIT_2:**

To Connecting an Azure AD with Service Principal in PowerShell, you can reference "[**Using a Service Principal to connect to a directory in PowerShell**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/active-directory/signing-in-service-principal?view=azureadps-2.0)".

To Assign AAD roles to groups in PowerShell, you can reference "[**Assign Microsoft Entra roles to groups**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity/role-based-access-control/groups-assign-role?tabs=aad-powershell)".

---

Comment: I already tried both Privileged Role Administrator and Global Administrator and I still have the same error